# Why no-nls utf8 locale is called C.UTF-8 in Debian and C.utf8 in Gentoo

Tags: debian, gentoo, locale, glibc

I usually worked with `Debian GNU/Linux`, and UTF-8 locale with no translations was called `C.UTF-8`. I assumed, this is de-facto name for such locale. Recently, I was installing `Gentoo GNU/Linux` distribution (profile `default/linux/amd64/17.0`) and discovered that such locale is called `C.utf8` there.

Why it is so? What is the reason for such incompatibility? Is it simple way to get UTF-8 untranslated locale, that works across all (or at least, glibc-based) distributions?